# Show in folder does not select file

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, file-manager, nemo

In various applications when I do "show file in folder" it simply open the file-manager (nemo) but does not select the actual file. How can I make show in folder also select the file?

Answer (score 5):

You would have to change each of the applications not to 'just' open with `nemo` with the directory as an argument but with the file.

Nemo already supports this, and you can easily test from a terminal with:

```
touch /var/tmp/xxx.txt
nemo /var/tmp/xxx.txt
```

this opens a view on `/var/tmp` with `xxx.txt` selected (tested with `nemo` version 2.0.8)

Comment: Do you have any idea how to change that for Google chrome? or some other app so I can see how its done.

Comment: @JebediahKerman Sorry, I have not, maybe there is an App for Chrome that does that.

Comment: are you sure there is not a system wide way of doing this?

Comment: No but I never heard of it. Nemo supports it, that is what I showed. If Chrome handles Nemo a directory (like it indicates it does, and in practice does) that is what you get. The system (or Nemo) cannot guess which file out of a directory is meant if it is not explicitly indicated. But you could change Nemo (by recompiling) to select e.g. the latest file created in a directory if it opens a directory, or select the biggest file, or the smallest, but that is coding and requires a selection criterium.

Comment: @JebediahKerman seems Firefox had this problem as well but it should be fixed in version 27 https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=417952

Comment: I find this really odd, because Chrome behaves correctly in Windows. Plus, it's not just in Chrome that I see this behavior happening -- it's a system-wide thing in Linux.